# Java - LibGDX - Problems with the process of rendering a Tiled map

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tiled, tmx

### The problem

I cannot seem to be able to get Tiled maps to render properly. I am using **LibGDX** as a library for loading the map *(Release 1.6.0)*.

### Video demonstration

I have created a video to show you the actual problem and make things easier by skipping the whole process of explaining it. [Here is a link](https://youtu.be/b6TzNGervts) to it.

### The code I've used

```
protected Level level;
protected OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
protected OrthographicCamera camera;
protected TiledMap map;
protected MainGameLoop game;
protected SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont font;
private int w, h;

public Level1(MainGameLoop game) {
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show() {
    w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 450 * (w / h);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
    camera.update();
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/map1.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(camera);
    mapRenderer.render();
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "Camera zoom: " + camera.zoom, 40, 40);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    mapRenderer.dispose();
    map.dispose();
    background.dispose();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    camera.zoom += amount;
    camera.update();
    return true;
}
    // Here go the rest of the methods, such as pause, resume, hide, keyDown, keyUp, keyTyped, touchDown, touchUp, touchDragged & mouseMoved.
```

### Solutions I've tried

I have tried using different numbers for the camera's **x** and **y** with no luck. I have also tried tranlating the camera to the proper position *(hardcoded it)*, as well as using another map *(different tilemap and dimensions)* but that did not work either.

### Conclusion

I can't seem to find a way to fix this problem. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by 'tiled map is not rendered properly'? I watched the video, but could not see, whats wrong with it.

Comment: @JoOko It is placed at a random position throughout the window, and as you can see in the video, the map's corners are not at the window's corner. In other words, the map doesn't stretch in order to fit the screen's dimensions, but just "sits" there, no matter where I place the camera's **x** and **y** coordinates. I hope this cleared things up. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick introduction

Ok after a good while, I managed to solve this matter by hardcoding some stuff. But it works properly, so I am happy with it.

### What I did to solve the problem

- First of all, I found out the exact number I had to use to scale up my Tiled map, which is this number: `3.125f` .
- Then, instead of using pixels for the camera, I used **my own units** *(something I should have done from the the first moment)*.
- After doing those two things, I noticed that the map was zoomed in a lot. So, by using the `scrolled` method from the `InputProcessor`, I managed to find the exact number the map had to be *"unzoomed"*.
- I also found out that if I call the `setToOrtho(false)` method from the `OrthographicCamera` object, it zooms the map in **19 times** for some weird reason. If that method does not get called, the map is zoomed in only **1 time**

### The code I am currently using

```
TiledMap tiledMap;
OrthographicCamera camera;
TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

final float WIDTH = 8000;
final float HEIGHT = 4500;
final float num = 3.125f;
@Override
public void show() {
    tiledMap = MapLoader.realm1_level1;
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, num);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    camera.zoom += 1f;
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
}
// This method was just used for testing to see where 
// the map was or should have been placed.
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT)
        camera.translate(-32, 0);
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT)
        camera.translate(32, 0);
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP)
        camera.translate(0, 32);
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.DOWN)
        camera.translate(0, -32);
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.NUM_1)
        tiledMap.getLayers().get(0).setVisible(!tiledMap.getLayers().get(0).isVisible());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.position.set(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    camera.zoom += amount;
    camera.update();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    tiledMap.dispose();
}
// And here go the rest of the methods that come from the 
//Screen and the InputProcessor interfaces.
```

### Notes

1. The numbers I used for the `WIDTH` and the `HEIGHT` variables work properly, **strictly** with tiled maps that their **width is 80 tiles**, and their **height is 45 tiles**.
2. If you are facing the same problem, you'll have to find the appropriate number to scale your map up/down, depending on the unit numbers you're using. **Trial and error is your only guide.** *If we ignore StackOverflow of course.*